# How do I retrieve the values of the coefficients after my Linear Regression model has finished training in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I would like to log the values of the coefficient variables after my Linear Regression model finishes training.

I've built a simple linear regression in tensorflow.js.

I have the weights being logged out to the browser every-time the model runs. Am I right in thinking that the weights are the coefficients?

How can I store the value of the weight / coefficient in a variable?

```js
tfvis.show.modelSummary({ name: "Model summary"}, model);
const layer = model.getLayer(undefined, 0);
tfvis.show.layer({ name: "Layer 1"}, layer);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using this  `.getWeights()` method in the following way, (at the end of each epoch)

```js
return model.fit(trainingFeatureTensor, trainingLabelTensor, {
                batchSize: 32,
                epochs: 20,
                validationSplit : 0.2,
                callbacks: {
                    onEpochEnd,
                    onEpochBegin : async function () {
                        await plotPredictionLine();
                        const layer = model.getLayer(undefined, 0);
                        tfvis.show.layer({ name: "Layer 1"}, layer);
                        model.layers[0].getWeights()[0].print()
                        
                    }
                }
            });
```